# Jquery Select parent li a if child element active

Tags: jquery, css

I spent hours looking for a CSS only then jQuery solution for this. I've seen this everywhere but not sure how to do one from the scratch.

What I want to do is, I have a menu as a list, and another list in it, and another. So this is a three level horizontal menu.

What I want to do is, when a child is selected, I want to change the background colour of the parent `li a` so it looks like breadcrumbs if you know what i mean.

This is my current css

```
.menu {
    z-index: 9999;
    position:relative;
    background-image: url(images/top_nav_lili_repeat.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x; height:38px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
.menu ul ul {
    display: none;
}
.menu ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
.menu ul {

    color: #797979;
    padding: 0 0px;

    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-table;
}
.menu ul:after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}
.menu ul li {
    float: left;
}
.menu ul li:hover {
    background: #4b545f;
}
.menu ul li:hover a {
    color: #EBAD2D;
}
.menu li a.seleted ul li a{ background-color:#ff0000;}
.menu ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 11px 16px;
    color: #bbb;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.menu ul li a.selected { background-color:#ff0000;}

.menu ul ul {
    background: #5f6975;
    border-radius: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    width: 200px;
}
.menu ul ul li {
    float: none;
    border-top: 1px solid #6b727c;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #575f6a;
    position: relative;
}
.menu ul ul li a {
    padding: 10px 16px;
    color: #fff;
}
.menu ul ul li a:hover {
    background: #4b545f;
}
.menu ul ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
```

and my current HTML menu looks like this.

```
<div class="menu">

            <ul>
    <li><a href="#" title="Menu Item 1">Home</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" title="Sub-Menu Item 1">Home link 1</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" title="Sub-Sub-Menu Item 1">Home Link 1 Link 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="Sub-Sub-Menu Item 2">Home Link 1 Link 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="Sub-Sub-Menu Item 3">Home Link 1 Link 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Sub-Menu Item 2">About</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" title="Sub-Sub-Menu Item 1">About 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="Sub-Sub-Menu Item 2">About 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="Sub-Sub-Menu Item 3">About 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Sub-Menu Item 3">Contact</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" title="Sub-Sub-Menu Item 1">Contact 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="Sub-Sub-Menu Item 2">Contact 2</a></li>
                    <li><a  class="selected" href="#" title="Sub-Sub-Menu Item 3">Contact 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>

</ul>
          </div>
```

If you look at the last `li a` `Contact 3` I have a class attached to it as `selected`, my CMS will add this class to the selected element. So What I want to do is change the background colour of the parent `<a>Contact</a>` and the `<a>Home</a>` with css or Jquery and I want this to crossbrowser compatible too. Thanks heaps guys.

Heres a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/8s3Bc/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need is to select anchor with the **selected** class, and iterate it's **li** [parents](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) to change their background.

In the following statement, I added **parent** class for parent **li** elements.

```
$('.menu li a.selected').parents('li').addClass('parent');​
```

And i defined background color for **parent** class.

```
.parent {
   background-color:#ff0000;
}
```

Here is the working example: [http://jsfiddle.net/dhMSN/](http://jsfiddle.net/dhMSN/1/)

Comment: How about for a three level menu? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35300274/how-to-keep-all-the-parent-except-the-first-li-highlighted-when-the-sub-li-is-ho Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

like this? http://jsfiddle.net/8s3Bc/5/

added this jquery

```
$('.menu ul ul > li').click(function(){
    $(this,'a').addClass('selected');
});​
```

and changed some css around, its on the fiddle

Answer (score 0):

May be @halilb answer is what you want, But look at this, may be improve your performance and look Feel of your menu.

Demo:http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/ddsmoothmenu.htm 
Code: https://github.com/dynamicdriverepo/ddsmoothmenu

Get Idea from this Here you can find proper implemented jQuery and css which you need.

Creating new functionality is Good, but not good when it's available for free and most important part **Proper Tested, with more functionality and well Structured code**

Note : I am not inspiring you to theft code every time or always copy someone code but save development time.