# How to keep all the parent except the first LI highlighted when the sub LI is hovered over

Tags: jquery, html, css

HTML:

```
<ul id="ulMenu">
    <li class="parent">
        <a href="">Software Update</a>
        <ul class="ulSubMenu">
            <li>
                <a href="">2010</a>
                <ul class="ulSubMenu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="">Version 1</a>
                        <ul class="ulSubMenu">
                            <li><a href="">Ver 1 Complete</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Ver 1 Not Yet</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="">2011</a>
                <ul class="ulSubMenu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="">Version 1</a>
                        <ul class="ulSubMenu">
                            <li><a href="">Ver 1 Complete</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Ver 1 Not Yet</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul.ulSubMenu > li > a:hover
{
      background-color: #008AAC;
      color: #C5F3FF;
}
.active {
    background-color: #008AAC;
    color: #C5F3FF;
}
```

JQuery:

I would like to add a script which sets any parent `LI` to the sub menu class to `active` except the parent `LI`

For example, if I hover "Ver 1 Complete" under the 2010 section it will change the styling with the `hover` css. I would also like to make the same style with the class `active` for Version 1 and 2010 LI.

How can I do that.

Comment: as you already tagged the question: jquery...

Comment: Still not entirely sure what's being asked

Comment: If I hover over `Ver 1 Complete`, I would like all the parent `LI`s to have the `active` class respectively except the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated my CSS to the following:

```
ul.ulSubMenu > li > a {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #C5F3FF;
    border: 1px solid #53E1FF;
    border-top: none;
    color: #008AAC;
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 15px;
    padding: 10px 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

ul.ulSubMenu > li:hover
{
    background-color: #008AAC;
    color: #C5F3FF;
}
ul.ulSubMenu > li:hover > a
{
    color: #C5F3FF;
    background-color: #008AAC;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should just change your `.active` rule to apply to all `li` elements that are hovered.

```
ul.ulSubMenu li:hover,
.active {
    background-color: #008AAC;
    color: #C5F3FF;
}
```

This should work as you want because when you hover over an element, all its parents are hovered as well.

Comment: It doesn't have the `.active` class created yet which OP is trying to achieve from what I understand, that simply hover the entire `li`

Comment: Thank you but I don't want `Software Update` to be changed just anything between that and the hovered `LI`.

Comment: @SiKni8 did you actually test the code ? See https://jsfiddle.net/gaby/eqjm0uk8/ it does not affect the "Software update". Also see https://jsfiddle.net/gaby/eqjm0uk8/1/ if you only want to affect the `a` tags and not the whole `li`

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli You are right, I didn't test it. Thanks... Testing it now.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/eqjm0uk8/3/  I have this but I don't want the child to be changed. Only the parent changed when hovered over the child.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/eqjm0uk8/5/ Works in Chrome but it is not working in IE9. Is there any way to accomplish the same maybe with Jquery?

Comment: @sikni8, it works on my ie9 (*emulation*).The only thing that fails is the background on the top bar (*but that is another issue*)